# Create a query from two tables, one with items in several columns, the other with its corresponding values

Tags: ms-access

In table1:

```
color -- Weight
Red -- 0.1
Yellow -- 0.2
Blue -- 0.3
<etc.>

In Table2:
color1 -- color2 -- color3 -- color4
Red -- Yellow -- Green -- Black
<etc>
```

What I want is a table (or query) like this:

```
color1 -- weight -- color2 -- weight -- color3 --- weight
Red -- 0.1 -- Yellow -- 0.2 -- Blue -- 0.3
Black -- 0.5 -- Magenta -- 0.8 -- Blue -- 0.3
<etc>
```

Maybe it's too obvious but I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Color1, DLookUp("Weight","Table1","Color = '" & [Color1] & "'") AS Weight1, 
Color2, DLookUp("Weight","Table1","Color = '" & [Color2] & "'") AS Weight2, 
Color3, DLookUp("Weight","Table1","Color = '" & [Color3] & "'") AS Weight3,
Color4, DLookUp("Weight","Table1","Color = '" & [Color4] & "'") AS Weight4
FROM Table2
```

Comment: This will work, but performance will be bad if there are many rows.

Answer (score -1):

It's not too obvious, if you haven't done a query like this before. You need **multiple joins** to Table1 from Table2.

In the query design editor, start with Table2. Then for each `color*` column you want to show, add an instance of Table1. Join each `color*` column with a different instance.

Then you can add the `color*` and each corresponding `weight` columns to the column list.